# Custom authorization using WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-web-api

I've implmented an service using MVC WEB API and i implemented a custom way to authenticate the requests. this is how it looks like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
    {
        try
        {                
            IDBModel DAO = new DBModelDAO();
            if (DAO.IsApiKeyValid(Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter))
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);                
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

However if the authentication fails i get redirected to this uri: 
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ftest

And i don't want that because i don't use the webbrowser for authenticating.

How can i disable this feature?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Zoli

Comment: Is there any AuthorizeAttribute for the controller class?

Comment: no, it looks like this
namespace DBModel.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/

        public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}

Comment: ok. please check your web.config's authentication node. Is the authentication mode is Forms? You should see the loginUrl=Acctiont/Login... as well.

Comment: i commented out the authentication part and it's okay now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The part:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

has to be commented and it won't redirect